# How can i make a relation between an image button and a function or activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, imagebutton

I must write a program with android which can find ssid and show it. My problem is how can i make a relation between an image button in first page and an activity or function in other page.

Buy the way i'm beginner and download the code of searching method because of that i can not recognize which one is the main method or function for pass it to setonclick method that i write for image button in first page?
please answer as soon as you can i need it immediately.

Comment: bound the image in your activity and add a OnClickListener.
Thats very easy to implement, even for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the ImageButton, and add the name of the function in the `On Click` property (Simply the name, like `myFunction`)

In your code, copy-paste this function and replace`myFunction` by the name of the function you chosed

```
public void myFunction(View v)
{
    String ssid = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextID)).getText().ToString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondView.class);
    intent.putExtra("SSID_KEY", ssid);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And replace `SecondView` by the class that displays your second page and `EditTextName` by the ID of your EditText.

In the `OnCreate` function of your second class, you can get your ssid using the following code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String ssid = getIntent().getStringExtra("SSID_KEY");
    //Do other work here.
}
```

Also, on top of the class containing the ImageView, don't forget to add these lines:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

Comment: Thank's. But i still have problems, totally i create 3 class: 
The first is mainactivity(for begining the program)
The second is start (which contain edit text and image button for search)
The third is wifissid(containing the code for search ssid). Now i encountered with some difficulties

1.My wifissid class have no oncreate function(I've mentioned before it's not my code and i download it)

2.As you said, i create "myfunction" in start page after oncreate function but i saw this error message:  " void is an invalid type for the variable myfunction "

What's youre suggestion

Comment: I modified my answer to reflect your needs.

Comment: Yes, you can send it using DropBox or any other file sharing website.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call another activity's method from your existing activity then you should use these steps.

1. First save the context or instance of the callee activity; for this you can use a class that holds your global data. In this class make the object of this activity.

   FirstActivity first = null;
2. When the callee activity is first created, initialize this instance.

   public void setFirstActivity(FirstActivity factivity)
   {
       first = factivity;
   }
3. And when you do need to call this callee activity's method then access this instance from this global class and with the help of this instance, you will have access to the methods of the callee activity.

   public FirstActivity  getFirstActivity() {
           return first ;
       }

use it to get access to the methods or instances of the activity.